# Is it possible to reverse-engineer a variable which has a moderation effect in a multiple regression, given the other variables?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, simulation, artificial-intelligence

I am interested in simulating a hypothetical variable Z which moderates the relationship between X (predictor) and Y (outcome variable), while controlling for C (covariate). All variables are continuous variables.

This moderation effect is of theoretical interest and my ultimate goal is to use a machine learning model to predict the variable Z using some other data which I have collected. This would allow me to identify underlying patterns which moderate the X-Y relationship.

I can use a two-step hierarchical multiple regression to establish whether a moderation effect exists.

Step 1 = X + C, outcome = Y

Step 2 = X + C + X*Z, outcome = Y

If the X*Z interaction term is significant, then a moderation effect exists.

If I already have X, Y, and C, is it possible to reverse-engineer or simulate the variable Z that would have a significant moderation effect in Step 2 of this model?

Comment: Hint:  for Z to act as a moderator, the relationship between {the residuals of X after it is regressed on C} and {the residuals of Y after it is regressed on C} would need to be a different relationship at different levels of Z.

Comment: @rolando2 thanks for comment. I should have mentioned that all variables are continuous variables.

I never though about regressing X on C and Y on C but this is going to be necessary too!